# Google Spreadsheet: E2-F2 even if i move the rows

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having an issue with google spreadsheets. I want to... have Cell C2 always contain the difference between cell E2 and F2 even if I move the row (i don't want the formula to adapt to that change of rows, the formula should still be E2-F2); so let's say E2 contains 5 and F2 contains 3, C2 would display 2. So let's say I switch row E and row F. Right now the result displayed would still be 2, and the formula in cell C2 would've changed to F2-E2. What I want is the formula not to change, and the result displayed would be -3.

`=INDIRECT(E2)-INDIRECT(F2)` didn't work for me - it gave me a reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INDIRECT` function expects a string parameter. So you would need to write

```
=INDIRECT("E2")-INDIRECT("F2")
```

But the better way to solve your problem would be to use absolute references

```
=$E$2-$F$2
```

Comment: Your second solution didn't work, it just changed to $F$2-$G$2 when i added a column. However first one seems to work so - thank you!